# toggle buttons state onclick elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I'm working with elementor, and I have four buttons, each of which displays a different element on the page (while the others are hidden at the same time).

Now, what I need is for these same buttons, which have an icon and text inside, to change that icon when clicked. However, I want it to work similarly to when I display the elements, meaning it should be like a hover effect.

When I click it, I want it to have a certain state, and when I click another button, I want it to return to its normal state.

I can also achieve this by changing the background image since I have the button design images, but I couldn't find any solutions online. Most solutions create switch-like buttons where pressing one button sets it to a certain state, even when another button is pressed.

The icons aren't from Font Awesome, are images from my elementor library.

Comment: Please share your attempted solution